# How to post a picture and .html at the same time on event click?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<div class="img-client"> 
<div class="client1"><a href="first_html.html"></a></div>
<div class="client2"><a href="second_html.html"></a></div>
<div class="client3"><a href="third_html.html"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="ajax"></div>

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".clients-img div").click(function()
  {

      $(".ajax").append('<img src="client1.png" alt="Question">');

        $(".ajax").load($(this).children().attr("href"));
 });
  return false;
});
```

On a click a picture and text below it shall be shown. If I erase `$(".ajax").load($(this).children().attr("href"));`
the picture works. But if I leave it in, only text is shown on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using load() function use append

```
$(".clients-img div").click(function(){
    $(".ajax").append('<img src="client1.png" alt="Question">');
    $(".ajax").append($(this).children().attr("href"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.load()`:

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML **into the matched element**.

So you want to `.get()` the data and append it to the `ajax` class.

EDIT:

```
 $(".clients-img div").click(function() {
  $.get($(this).children().attr("href"), function(data) {
   $(".ajax").append('<img src="client1.png" alt="Question">').append(data)
  })
 });
```

Comment: Can you write it here? I tried something like this $.get("first_html.html").success(function(data) {
          $('.ajax').html(data);

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the image with the .load content. Since the image is already being appended, if you just reversed the order of the two it should work fine.